# Navigate to a specific route without reloading the page but update router.url

Tags: angular, typescript

While navigating to a specific route using `router.navigate` reloads the page and **ADDS** the new route in `router.url`. Below is the code for navigation using `router.navigate`.

```
navigateTo(){
    const queryParamaters = {}
    queryParamaters['siteNo'] = '1234';
    this.router.navigate(['/sites'], { queryParams: queryParameters });
}
```

So I used `location.replaceState` for navigation which performs navigation without reloading the page but does **NOT** update `router.url`. Below is the code for navigation using `location.replaceState`.

```
navigateTo(){
    let url = '/sites';
    let queryString = '?siteNo=1234'
    this.location.replaceState(url, queryString);
}
```

I need a solution where navigation to a specific route happens without page reload and also updates the `router.url`.

**app.route.ts**

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'sites',
    component: SitesComponent
}];
```

Comment: could you please share your code

Comment: Can you add some more details ? Can you share your app.router.module.ts and structure of your code ?

Comment: @Peatyush, router.navigate "replace" the `<router-oultet>` with the component you has defined in your  Routes, check if you're navigate abslute or relative path, if you want to route in a chil dor not... give us some more data

Comment: Added code snippets as requested.

Comment: I suggest use paramMap  (a router like sites/1234) nor query, but in both cases you need subscribe to activateRouter.queryparamMaps or activateRouter.paramMap, see the docs: https://angular.io/guide/router#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments

Comment: @Eliseo The requirement here is to use query params and not path params. So i need to use query params strictly.

Comment: then subscribe to activateRouter.queryparamMaps in the ngOnInit (yes, is also an observable): https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#queryParamMap -it's similar to subcribe to paramMap-

Answer (score 0):

To change the URL without reloading the component associated to it we can use Query Params .

```
constructor (private router: Router,private route: ActivatedRoute)


this.router.navigate([],{
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams : {
        anyName: Value
      }
```

By Using this logic we can pass anything in anyName to give the QueryParams a name and Value of our choice to show in URL which only updates the URL and doesnt load the component